How to upgrade hsqldb to 2.7.1 version for jdk-8 using Apache ivy?
Our project is on jdk-8 and Apache ivy is being used to fetch the dependencies. We need to update hsqldb library from version 2.3.3 to 2.7.1. After updating the ivy xml
<dependency org="org.hsqldb" name="hsqldb" rev="**2.7.1**" conf="build,test,schema,guiwar->default"/>

The default 2.7.1 is being downloaded which is only compatible for Java 11 and higher. We need to fetch the hsqldb-2.7.1-jdk8.jar instead of the default one.
Please suggest something which would resolve this.
